# Excel 2013: Convert Hours and Minutes from hh:mm:ss formatted cell in decimal number

Tags: excel, time, cell

I use Excel 2013 and have a cell with the following value:

"08.01.1900  1:45:00"

that will be displayed inside the cell as: "193:45:00" - meaning 193 hours, 45 minutes and 00 seconds (see the first image below).

*Here is screen of how it looks like and the formatting of the cell*
[how it looks like]

[image]

QUESTION: **How I can in cell "Salary" to get decimal number, like - 193,45?** Help me, please.

*The cell is formatted as Time (see the image below)*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have `Q2 = 12:30` (or `12,5` hours where `0,5 hour=30min`)  and `R2 = 15,5` UAH/hour  and since you want to calculate salary, you should multiple `12,5*15,5=193,75`.
Follow next steps to achieve the desired result:

1. Write next formula in `S2`: `=Q2*24*R2` (since time stored in Excel as part of a day, we need to multimply by `24` . Your value  `12:30` is actually `0,520833333333333` ,you can see it if you'd format `Q2` as number. Myltiplication `0,520833333333333` by `24` gives you exactly `12,5`)
2. Format your `S2` as number

the result would be `0,52*24*15,5 = 193,75` and this value is what you actually need.

Comment: simoco, thank you very much.

I can not understand the latter, why deemed Excel and displays the value 193.75 ?
And if we multiply two values ​​on the rate of 12.3 hours per hour = 15.5, we obtain 190.65
What's wrong with formula excel?

Comment: `12:30` is not `12.3`. So, `12:30` means 12 hours and half hour, or `12.5` hours (30 min = 0.5 hour, and  12:30 = 12 hours + 0.5 hour= 12.5 hours)